# Javascript how to skip $& in replace() function

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, reference

How to skip replacing special $& in replace() function

I try to add \ ($\&) but without any results

```js
var url = 'http://www.example.com/?a=b&c=c&d=$cid$&e=e';
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {link} consectetur adipiscing elit. {link} id porttitor quam rhoncus in.';
var output = txt.replace(/{link}/gi, url);
console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$$` on your replacement for scaping `$`

Or fix the url itself with this `url.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$')`

```js
var url = 'http://www.example.com/?a=b&c=c&d=$cid$&e=e';
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, {link} consectetur adipiscing elit. {link} id porttitor quam rhoncus in.';
var output = txt.replace(/{link}/gi, url.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$'));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Hi, bur urls are from outside and `url.replace('$&','$$&')` do nothing :/ is any other option to skip this?

Comment: I updated my answer. For fixing the url you must search `\$` (on the search you scape things with backslash) and then replace by 2 $, however since each dollar must be scaped you must use 4 $

Comment: And that what im looking for! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: You are welcome :-). Remember that you can mark the answer as 'accepted' if It worked for you @LordHunter